# Connecting to API via remote browser

Tags: json, browser, remote-access

I'm running a process on one system that hosts a JSON API at 127.0.0.1:42000. I would like to connect this API from a remote system. In particular, I would like to route the data to a web browser.

I've tried using my browser to connect to the local IP address of the machine on that port, but the browser is reporting that there is no response. I don't know much TCP, HTTP, and the like so unfortunately I can't really think of what to try next or even what to search for. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I found a work-around that does what I need. I set up an HTTP server for a directory `~/my-http-server` on port 54321 using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 54321`. I also set up a repeating script to dump the contents of API call into a file named `api.html` in that directory: `watch -n1 wget 127.0.0.1:42000 -q -O - | cat >> ~/my-http-server/api.html`. It is far from a perfect solution, but I am at least able to access a cached version of the API call.

Answer (score 0):

Are remote system and host on the same network? if yes then get the IP address of the host system and use that ip address instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Yes it's a local network. Is there any reason the server would block incoming requests?

Comment: Did you try with the actual ip address of host system? if yes could you post the result of that?

Comment: The page says "Can't establish a connection to 192.168.0.13:42000. The site might be temporarily unavailable" That's the correct IP. I'm able to connect via SSH.